# Symfony2 Embedded forms delete button functionality

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, symfony

I have created an embedded form in Symfony2 which has many "Employees" in one "Department". Now, the Addition of many employees with their "Firstname" and "Lastname" is working fine on the "Department" form (I have used jQuery for this purpose). I want the "Delete" button functionality on the form, which I am unable to figure out. Can anyone help me with the delete button function?

DepartmentType.php

```
<?php

namespace InstituteEvents\FormBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class DepartmentType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('employees','collection', array(
            'type' => new EmployeeType(),
            'prototype' => true,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'by_reference' =>false
         ))    
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'InstituteEvents\FormBundle\Entity\Department'
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'department';
}
}
```

EmployeeType.php

```
<?php

namespace InstituteEvents\FormBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class EmployeeType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('firstname')
        ->add('lastname')
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'InstituteEvents\FormBundle\Entity\Employee'
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'employee';
}
}
```

index.html.twig - This file contains the "add employees" button functionality in jQuery. Here I want the "delete employees" button + functionality. I don't know javascript or jQuery properly, so I need help in adding the "delete employees" button + the code for it.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var index = 0;
    var prototype = $('ul.form-employees').data('prototype');
    $('#form-employee-btn').on('click', function() { 
        var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index++);
        var newLi = $('<li></li>');

        newLi.append(newForm);
        $(this).before(newLi);
    });
});
</script>    
<form method = "post">
{{ form_label(form.name, 'Department Name') }}
{{ form_widget(form.name) }}

<ul class="form-employees" data-prototype = "{{ form_widget(form.employees.vars.prototype)|e }}">
   <input id="form-employee-btn" type="button" value="Add Employees"/>
</ul>

   {{ form_widget(form._token) }}

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
```

Comment: You should use the docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-tags-to-be-removed as all you need is in there

Comment: I could not convert from the cookbook to the jQuery code as above in index.html.twig for "Delete Employees" button and its code. Please help

Comment: Hey Udan can you help me with the jQuery code for the "Delete Employees" button? As I don't know jQuery

Comment: You've not set the `allow_delete` attribute on your `DepartmentType` form. How to handle deletion is covered extensively [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) (PHP + jQ code)

Comment: Thank You Elias Van Ootegem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the instructions found [in the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html):

In your `DepartmentType` form class, set the `EmployeeType` collection's `allow_delete` attribute to `true`:

```
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('employees','collection', array(
            'type' => new EmployeeType(),
            'prototype' => true,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,//add this
            'by_reference' =>false
         )
    );
```

Next, add the delete button (either through the builder in your `EmployeeType` form (`->add('delete', 'button')`), or manually (using JS in the tempalte). Then attach an event listener to the form. Assuming you've added the delete button like so:

```
//EmployeeType:
$builder->add('delete', 'button', ['attr' => ['class' => 'delete-employee']]);
```

If you're adding the buttons using JS in the view, then this code should do the trick:

```
$('#department-form-selector').children('employee-form-selector').each(function(i)
{
    $(this).append('<button name="delete' + i + '" class="delete-employee">Delete</button>');
});
```

When the buttons have been added (or are about to be added), attach a listener using jQ. The buttons needn't be in the DOM at this stage, because we're using event delegation, instead of direct binding:

```
$('#department-form-selector').on('click', '.delete-employee', function()
{
    $(this).closest('form').delete();//remove element
    //optionally submit department form via AJAX call to persist the delete
    return false;//stop event
});
```

Now, to handle the form (assuming the entities are set up properly):

```
//in the controller that handles the form:
if ($form->isValid())
{
    //1 => we need to query for the data in the DB, so we know what to delete
    $current = $service->getCurrentDepartmentWithEmployees();
    //get the current employees, that need to be updated
    $oldEmployees = new ArrayCollection();
    foreach ($current->getEmployees() as $employee)
        $oldEmployees->add($employee);
    //2 => get the form data
    $department = $form->getData();
    //3 => check if one or more eployees were deleted
    foreach ($oldEmployees as $employee)
    {
        if (!$department->getEmployees()->contains($employee))
        {//employee was removed, update entity/entities
            $current->getEmployees()->removeElement($employee);
            //depending on the relations you've specified:
            $employee->setDepartment(null);
            $em->persist($employee);
            $em->persist($current);
        }
    }
    $em->flush();
}
```

Note that this code is *untested*. It's the basic flow of a worst-case-scenario deletion (bi-directional, one to many relation that is inversed, but no ondelete cascade restrictions have been set).
Using this code as a reference, you should be able to work it out, though

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I wanted to add the "Delete Employees" button in the "twig"(index.html.twig) as I have done for "Add" button and not in "EmployeeType" .ie                          <ul class="form-employees" data-prototype = "{{ form_widget(form.employees.vars.prototype)|e }}">
   <input id="form-employee-btn" type="button" value="Add Employees"/>
</ul>                                                            Similarly I wanted to have "Delete Employees" button and have the delete functionality in "index.html.twig" ? Can you provide the code for that as a whole in "index.html.twig" ?

Comment: As "Add" button I have not provided in "DepartmentType" or in "EmployeeType" but I have included the code for "Add" button in Twig using HTML

Comment: @sachintendulkar: I've added both ways to add a delete button for each employee (the bit containing `$(this).append()`). The `deleteAll` button is basically the same as a single delete, just call `remove()` on all employee form elements, and submit that form, and process it in the same way. That's a simple matter of adding a button element + event handler that queries the DOM for all employee forms, loops over them (`$('emplyee-form-selector').each(function(){$(this).remove()})`), and submit the form

Comment: @sachintendulkar: Apart from that: no, I'm not going to provide you with all the code, that's not my job. I'm prepared to help you if you're stuck with a specific problem, but I'm not going to do your work for you, free of charge... sorry

Comment: I would be very very grateful of you if you could provide me the code for "Delete Employees" button and its functionality in index.html.twig as I have for "Add" button and its code in "index.html.twig" as a whole, please

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am sorry if I have offended you, I am new to Symfony2 so I had asked for the code

Comment: @sachintendulkar: I'm not easily offended, don't worry. I just feel that it's better in the long run for you to try to work it out yourself. If you're new to Symfony2, you still need to find out how it all works. My posting copy-pastable code isn't going to help you with that. Instead, I've given you all the steps that you need to go through to get the desired outcome, and now it's up to you to bring it all together. Trust me: you'll learn a lot faster this way

Comment: Thanks for the advice Elias Van Ootegem.

Comment: I added the delete button in "EmployeeType" and $('#department-form-selector').on('click', '.delete-employee', function()
{
    $(this).closest('form').delete();//remove element
    //optionally submit department form via AJAX call to persist the delete
    return false;//stop event
}); in index.html.twig, so when I click on "Add" button then it gives firstname and lastname field and a "delete" button.But when I click on "Delete" button then It doesnot remove the fields of firstname and lastname